# how to write a stored procedure for adding the values in the table when we have two or more values for the same data in stored procedure MSSQl

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am having a table as shown below here i have to write a stored procedure such that when i get the value for search in "uid" i have to post all the data from "otheruid" and amount such that if any duplicate values exist in "otheruid" i have to club the amount across them.
the example table and output is as follows

Table:-
[image: Table]

Output:-
when i send UID to stored proc with value 1 it should appear like

[image: check here for output image]

so this the deficulty i am facing to get the output can any one please help me to solve this.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Please tag correctly

Comment: share your stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this does exactly what you want, as your second image confuses me a little, as I am not sure if you just want the one row to be returned, or all and if you need to also add the 'OtherUID'? Anyway, hopefully this will get you started and if you don't need the OtherUID you can remove it from the procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spName]

@intUID         INT ,
@intOtherUID    INT
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF(@intUID IS NOT NULL AND @intOtherUID IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SELECT          [UID],
                        [OTHERUID],
                        SUM([AMOUNT]) AS [AMOUNT]
        FROM            TABLE
        WHERE           [UID]       = @intUID
        AND             [OTHERUID]  = @intOtherUID
        GROUP BY        [UID],[OTHERUID]
        ORDER BY        [UID],[OTHERUID]
    END
ELSE IF (@intUID IS NOT NULL AND @intOtherUID IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        SELECT          [UID],
                        [OTHERUID],
                        SUM([AMOUNT]) AS [AMOUNT]
        FROM            TABLE
        WHERE           [UID]       = @intUID
        GROUP BY        [UID],[OTHERUID]
        ORDER BY        [UID],[OTHERUID]
    END
ELSE IF (@intUID IS NULL AND @intOtherUID IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SELECT          [UID],
                        [OTHERUID],
                        SUM([AMOUNT]) AS [AMOUNT]
        FROM            TABLE
        WHERE           [OTHERUID]  = @intOtherUID
        GROUP BY        [UID],[OTHERUID]
        ORDER BY        [UID],[OTHERUID]
    END
IF(@intUID IS NULL AND @intOtherUID IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        SELECT          [UID],
                        [OTHERUID],
                        SUM([AMOUNT]) AS [AMOUNT]
        FROM            TABLE
        GROUP BY        [UID],[OTHERUID]
        ORDER BY        [UID],[OTHERUID]
    END
END
```

You can then decide what IDs you pass, to determine what you get returned.
Hope it helps

Comment: Thnks  ,but i dont want otheruserid as input parameter

Answer (score 0):

/*

declare @rc  int 
execute @rc =SP_SelectAmount
@UID             =  2

*/

alter procedure SP_SelectAmount
@UID                int

as

begin

select   distinct  otheruserid, sum(amount) as TotalAmount ,UID from UOMID  WHERE UID=@UID  group by otheruserid  ,UID

end